# Programing a Bare Pic32

Tags: uploading

I recently received two types of Pic32 microcontrollers from Microchip, specifically the `PIC32MX270F256B` and the `PIC32MX230F256B`. I would like to use an Arduino Uno to setup the bootloader and to do all the programming. I found a tool to upload to the board [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ardupic32/downloads), but as it is from a 2012 forum [here](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m653443.aspx), I cannot figure out what it is exactly used for. It seems to be able to upload hex files, but in which format and to what is unclear to me. I also found Arduino bootloaders for a similar group of microcontroller [here](https://github.com/chipKIT32/PIC32-avrdude-bootloader), however I cannot tell exactly which version I need, if any, or how to upload it.

Any help on how to use these tools or others would be greatly appreciated as my only experience with Arduino before this is with a simple to program to Arduino Uno.

Comment: To all who have an better idea than I do as to how to tag this, feel free to suggest changes or just edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

I am unaware of any Arduino-based tools for installing a bootloader on a PIC32. If you are going to work with PIC32 you really should invest in a proper programmer.

I often use (pretty much throw-away) Chinese clones of the PICkit2 programmer. You can find them on eBay nice and cheap.  Genuine Microchip programmers are pretty expensive, so these cheap clones are quite handy...

You will also want to install the [chipKIT environment](https://chipkit.net/wiki/index.php?title=ChipKIT_core) into the Arduino IDE.

When it comes to the bootloader there are no official boards that use those chips. So you will need to compile your own version, which is not trivial. You will need to install MPLAB-X and the XC32 compiler and create a new profile within the project with the right settings for your board.

And then of course you will have to craft a board configuration for your custom board.

All-in-all it's quite a complex task porting a new board / chip to the chipKIT environment, and you would probably be better off directly using MPLAB-X and programming directly in C (although it's harder to get started in that environment). The PIC32 chips are considerably more complicated to work with than little AVR chips.